# Calculating $p$-value for a $\chi^2$-distribution?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

The sugar content of the syrup in canned peaches is **normally distributed**. Suppose that the variance is thought to be $18 \text{mg}^2$. A random sample $n = 10$ of cans yields a **sample standard deviation** of $s = 4.8$ mg.

Test the hypothesis $H_0: \sigma^2 = 18$ versus $H_a: \sigma^2 \neq 18$ using $\alpha = 0.05$.

**Find $p$-value for the test**.

The solution is shown below: 
[image: Solution]

I have no idea, now they did $p$-value calculations. Can someone please tell the steps to evaluate $p$-value?

Comment: they have looked up the values in a statistical table for a $\chi^2_9$ distribution

Comment: how did they get 0.2418?

Comment: In the statistical tables there is a column for $x$, and the value tabulated denotes $P(\chi_9^2 > x)$. The value printed is 0.2418.

Sometimes tables give you $x$ to 1 decimal place only. In which case you interpolate between 11.5 and 11.6.

Comment: In this day and age, you don't look it up in tables, you use software that can compute the CDF of chi-squared distributions. But if you really want to compute it by hand, it's available in "closed form".

Comment: Actually $0.2418$ is not quite right: Maple gives $0.241740882015360$, so the correct value to $4$ decimal places is $0.2417$.   Of course, this doesn't make a difference in the outcome of the test.